# Can I have kCATransitionReveal + kCATransitionFade working at the same time?

Tags: ios, core-animation, caanimation

What I want to achive is a kCATransitionReveal effect while it also fades out.

I am using the animation to animate an UIImageView content change. With kCATransitionReveal the old image goes away while the new one is already visible bellow it. I want the old one to fade out at the same time it moves away.

I have tried using `CAAnimationGroup` adding two `CATransition` one configured with `kCATransitionReveal` and other with `kCATransitionFade`, but I can't see any animation at all.

Comment: Have you tried animating the `alpha` value at the same time (instead of the `kCATransitionFade`)

Comment: Yes, the problem is that affects to the image being revelated and not the one going away.

Comment: Instead of using a built in transition, just write your own animation.

Comment: I don't think it is that simple. `CATransition` seems to add a second layer, and then it animates both layers to achieve the desired effect. So if I am not wrong the solution is to: 1) add a copy of the current layer on top, 2) update the image in the background layer, 3) animate position and opacity of the added layer, 4) once animation is done remove the layer used for animation. Sadly this doesn't fit my existing code very well and a major refactoring will be required.